# Accept a range and Print all the Peterson numbers within the given range

Tags: java, numbers

I managed to identify the Peterson number but am having problems to get it within the loop.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Special_no

{

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int n,r,s=0;int i,f,m=0;int a,j=0;
            System.out.println("Enter the Lower Limit : ");
            n=sc.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Enter the Upper Limit : ");
            a=sc.nextInt();
            for(j=n;j<a;j++)
            {  
              m=j;
              do
              { 
                r=m%10;
                f=1;
                for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
                {   
                   f=f*i;
                 }   
                s=s+f;
                 m=m/10;
              }       
              while(m>0);
              if(s==j)
               System.out.print(j+",");
            }
        }
}
```

During runtime, after I enter the upper and lower limit the program accepts it but it doesn't give me any output.

How do I correct it?

Comment: By doing some debugging.

Comment: as OliverCharlesworth said do some debugging, but just for a hint, what does the `while(m>0);` do? why do you have it there?

Comment: is `while(m>0);` correct? have u tried with out `;` ?

Comment: @Skaros, it's a `do...while()` and not just a `while()`, so that's not necessarily the problem.

Comment: @JimLewis you are right, didnt see the `do{` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your loops for this:

```
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        x=i;
        s=0;
        while(x>0)
        {
            r=x%10;
            fact=1;
            for(k=1;k<=r;k++)
            {
                fact=fact*k;
            }
            s=s+fact;
            x=x/10;
        }
        if(s==i)
        System.out.print(i+"  ");
    }
```

You're Welcome.